# How to insert the ID value from a text in a database

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, forms

I've this form and everything works perfect, when the user complete the form all the parameters go to the database and I can show them back, but I've a little problem with something. I've been inserting one field from codebehind like a constant, one of my fiel expect a int value but in the form you select that value as string. For example you select "Pink" in the form but the data base is expecting a int value. The table from Pink has Pink associated to a idValue, e.g. IDColor = 45 Color=Pink. So, what I really need to do is be able to send the ID associated with Pink to the database and when I call back that row, I need to show PInk instead of 45. I know how to make the connection, but I don't know hoy to make the consult. Thanks for your time for reading this and sorry for the long post.

This is the code for insert in the database after the form is ready

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IdColonia", 2))
```

I need to change that "2" for the ID associated with the parameter in the form.
This is the callback for this particular field

```
 Me.txtDirColonia.Text = Me.gridDatos.Rows(Me.gridDatos.SelectedIndex).Cells(7).Text
```

I call back the `ID` of the table but I need the actual Color.

Comment: If you have both the ID(45) and the Color(Pink) in the Database, why don't you just populate the Grid with the Color Column and not use the ID column?

Comment: I solved there were different tables but I make a View of both tables and then a `select` to te view a retrieve the info that I need it